# How do I make customer telephone number mandatory?

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento-2.1.3

How do I make the customer **contact telephone** a **mandatory field** during the checkout process on the Magento 2.1.3?

Part of our service is to call the customer before the delivery is made to ensure someone is available to receive the items.

Comment: Do you have custom checkout? Stock magento 2.1.3 has telephone field required already see this http://prnt.sc/f4hfus

Comment: Honestly I'm not 100% sure, i do have Paypal Express and a Barclay Card merchant portal added. www.willowbay.co.uk

Answer (score 1):

Run this MySQL command on your database.

```
UPDATE eav_attribute SET is_required='1' WHERE attribute_code='telephone';
```

> The **Default** is 0, but maybe some third-party module has changed it to no required.

Comment: it is set to 1 by default.

Comment: If he is using a custom module, maybe it've changed to 0.

Comment: I've just looked at the field in SQL and attribute is already set to 1

Answer (score 0):

You should first figure out which is the js module that defines ui component and that is used for that particular input.

In general, each separate form field type will use its own js module. For example, if you open magento folder

```
/vendor/magento/moduleui/view/base/web/js/form/element
```

you will notice how modules are named: text.js, textarea.js, media.js, file-uploader.js etc.

I would guess (but you should check in details) that the telephone component is used in a regular input, which is represented by abstract.js

So, if you just open that file

```
/vendor/magento/moduleui/view/base/web/js/form/element/abstract.js
```

you will see some code like this

```
return Element.extend({
    defaults: {
        visible: true,
        preview: '',
        focused: false,
        required: false,
        disabled: false,
        ... other code here ...
```

Therefore, you should override the ui component in use (but please locate it yourself) in such a fashion that you will merely change the `required` value under the `defaults`.

Your code could be similar to

```
return Element.extend({
    defaults: {
        required: true
    }
});
```

In is good to notice that `extend` here is basically the extend method from underscore which will shallow copy, i.e you will already get all of the remaining properties from the `defaults` in your component as well.

Please browse on your own how to locate the actual ui component in use and how to override it in your module.